# How do you show this HTML output: 1 + 3 + 4 + 17 + 8 + 15 = 48 using XSLT..?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I need to know how to use xPath’s numeric function within a style sheet to show the HTML output:

1 + 3 + 4 + 17 + 8 + 15 = 48

The style sheet needs to use numeric function, position(), and a test and conditional statement to present the HTML output.

This is the xml data:

```
<account>
   <number>1</number>
   <number>3</number>
   <number>4</number>
   <number>17</number>
   <number>8</number>
   <number>15</number>
</account>
```

This is all I have in my .xsl so far.. It just shows the sum 48...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select='sum(//number)'/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you,

Shaun

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: This is preparation for a test next week. The above question was in last years test ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="account">
        <html>
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="number"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(' = ',sum(number))"/>              
            </p>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="number">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::number">
            <xsl:text> + </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <p>1 + 3 + 4 + 17 + 8 + 15 = 48</p>
</html>
```

---

Also, if you must use `position()` in the stylesheet, you could change the `xsl:if` to:

```
<xsl:if test="position() != count(/*/number)">
    <xsl:text> + </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 this is almost a one-liner:

```
<xsl:template match="account">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-join(number, ' + '), '=', sum(number)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Oh, you said you needed to use position(). If you think you'll be disqualified for not using position() then you can change it to:

```
<xsl:template match="account">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-join(number, ' + '), '=', sum(number)*position()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But you might then be disqualified for mocking the stupidity of the judges.